# Centering Multiple Items

Tags: javascript, algorithm

In my app, I have a bunch of rectangles.

[image]

I am trying to horizontally centerize all of these rectangles on the screen. (The center is screen_width/2)

Here is my code so far (for your viewing pleasure),

```
            for (var j=0;j<rectangles.length;j++){
                rectangle=rectangles[j];
                                    var margin=120;
                var coefficent=0;
                var center_index=Math.ceil(rectangles.length/2);
                if (j>center_index){
                     coefficent=1;
                }else if (j<center_index){
                    coefficent=-1;
                }


                var x=(screen.width-rectangle.width)/2+j*margin*coefficent;
                rectangle.SetX(x);

                }
```

This code puts everything in the center (not cool).

Any help on this problem would be splendidly appreciated.

Edit:

Sorry for not being clear,

Heres another image to be more clear (the line, is the center line):

[image]

So you can see, that we are shifting all the rectangles so that the middle rectangle is in the center.

**Like when you press the center button to centerize text horizontally on a Word Document, I am trying to do this with rectangles.**

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Why don't you use CSS to center them? JS is hardly the right tool for this.

Comment: Oh, this is just a smaller example of the real problem (this isn't the actual problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure without full the code (I would suggest jsfiddle) but it seems you are using center = width/2 for more than 2 rectangles. if you have 3 rectangles, using the absolute center to position will not work. What I would suggest is centering by dividing the width by the number of rectangles then using that as a center point for each rectangle, ie (untested pseudo code as I don't have the full code. I also added a few un needed variables like currentRectHalf width to try to make things clearer):

```
  var width=500; //fill in with your width
  var margin=120; //margin
  var numRectangles=rectangles.length; //from your example
  var offset=width/numRectangles;
  for(var i=0;i<numRectangles;i++) {
    currentRectHalfWidth=rectangle.width/2;
    currentCenter=(offset+1)*offset+margin-currentRectHalfWidth; //+1 because of zero index array
    rectangle.SetX(x);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if you have not set the Y value of your rectangles. Somewhere in your code you need to set their Y values so they are not all in the exact center.

Comment: Hi, I just updated my question, I hope you will be able to check it out.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to move the rectangles a certain distance towards the center?

Comment: Like when you press the center button to centerize text, I am trying to do this with rectangles.